# How to make zoom out effect with css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In the hero section parallax effect is used, and also a zoom out effect: http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/

How can I make the zoom out effect?

In my implementation, I converted and copied HTML to JSX. It will only **reduce** background image size, but not zoom out, why?

What Codrop makes different?

[my rendered gif implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCaTY.gif)

```
import Navbar from 'tikexModule/components/Navbar'
import Footer from './Footer'

interface Props {
    children?: React.ReactNode
    isNavbarTransparent?: Boolean
}
const Layout = ({ children, isNavbarTransparent }: Props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div
                className="parallax-mirror ken-burn-center"
                data-source-id="section_RIZ3d"
                style={{
                    visibility: 'hidden',
                    zIndex: -100,
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '0px',
                    left: '0px',
                    overflow: 'hidden',
                    transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
                    height: '450px',
                    width: '1440px',
                }}
            >
                <img
                    className="parallax-slider"
                    src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/hd-1.jpg"
                    style={{
                        transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        left: '0px',
                        height: '810px',
                        width: '1440px',
                        maxWidth: 'none',
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            <div
                className="parallax-mirror"
                data-source-id="section_oxy7k"
                style={{
                    visibility: 'hidden',
                    zIndex: -100,
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '0px',
                    left: '0px',
                    overflow: 'hidden',
                    transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
                    height: '595px',
                    width: '1440px',
                }}
            >
                <img
                    className="parallax-slider"
                    src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/hd-2.jpg"
                    style={{
                        transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        left: '0px',
                        height: '810px',
                        width: '1440px',
                        maxWidth: 'none',
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            <div
                className="parallax-mirror ken-burn-center"
                data-source-id="section_5ZtkF"
                style={{
                    visibility: 'visible',
                    zIndex: -100,
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: '-70px',
                    left: '0px',
                    overflow: 'hidden',
                    transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
                    height: '972px',
                    width: '1440px',
                }}
            >
                <img
                    className="parallax-slider"
                    src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/hd-1.jpg"
                    style={{
                        transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: '-131px',
                        left: '0px',
                        height: '810px',
                        width: '1440px',
                        maxWidth: 'none',
                    }}
                />
            </div>
            <div id="preloader" style={{ display: 'none' }} />
            <nav
                id="nav"
                className="scroll-change menu-classic  menu-fixed menu-transparent  light align-right  menu-one-page"
                data-menu-anima="fade-in"
                data-scroll-detect="true"
            >
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="menu-brand">
                        <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music">
                            <img
                                className="logo-default"
                                src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/08/logo-light.svg"
                                alt=""
                                style={{}}
                            />
                            <img
                                className="logo-retina"
                                src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/08/logo-light.svg"
                                alt=""
                                style={{}}
                            />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <i className="menu-btn" />
                    <div className="menu-cnt">
                        <ul id="main-menu">
                            <li className=" ">
                                <a href="#overview">Overview</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className=" ">
                                <a href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className=" ">
                                <a href="#features">Features</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className=" ">
                                <a href="#news">News</a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="   dropdown ">
                                <a href="#">Pages</a>
                                <ul
                                    className="dropdown-menu fade-in"
                                    style={{
                                        animationDuration: '250ms',
                                        transitionTimingFunction: 'ease',
                                        transitionDelay: '0ms',
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <li className="dropdown-submenu ">
                                        <a href="#">Sites</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/saas/">
                                                    Saas
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/fintech/">
                                                    Fintech
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/chat/">
                                                    Chat
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/sport/">
                                                    Sport
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/food/">
                                                    Food
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/">
                                                    Music
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/photo/">
                                                    Photo
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/travel/">
                                                    Travel
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/news/">
                                                    News
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/">
                                                    Intro
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="dropdown-submenu ">
                                        <a href="#">Pages</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/intro/about-us/">
                                                    About
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/careers/">
                                                    Careers
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/faq/">
                                                    Faq
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/stories/">
                                                    Success stories
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/pricing-one/">
                                                    Pricing one
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/pricing-two/">
                                                    Pricing two
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/team/">
                                                    Team
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/shop/">
                                                    Shop
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="dropdown-submenu ">
                                        <a href="#">Blog</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/intro/blog-one/">
                                                    Blog one
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/intro/blog-two/">
                                                    Blog two
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/blog/2019/09/03/who-was-the-man-wearing-the-1-3-million-watch-stolen-in-spain/">
                                                    Post
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className="dropdown-submenu ">
                                        <a href="#">Contacts</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/contacts-one/">
                                                    Contacts one
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/contacts-two/">
                                                    Contacts two
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li className=" ">
                                                <a href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/contacts-three/">
                                                    Contacts three
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li className=" ">
                                        <a
                                            target="_blank"
                                            href="https://templates.themekit.dev/codrop/elements/components/buttons.html"
                                        >
                                            Elements
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div className="menu-right">
                            <div className="menu-custom-area">
                                <a className="btn btn-xs btn-border btn-circle" href="#">
                                    Download App
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <main className="footer-parallax-cnt" style={{ marginBottom: '442px' }}>
                <section
                    id="section_5ZtkF"
                    className="section-image hc-cmp-section  light  section-bottom-layer  ken-burn-center"
                    data-parallax="scroll"
                    data-natural-height={1080}
                    data-natural-width={1920}
                    data-position
                    data-image-src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/hd-1.jpg"
                >
                    <div className="container ">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div
                                id="column_3LmOZ"
                                className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-12  "
                                style={{}}
                            >
                                <hr id="C2Ryb" className="hc-cmp-space space    " />
                            </div>
                            <div
                                id="column_OfRKu"
                                className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-6   fade-in"
                                style={{
                                    position: 'relative',
                                    animationDuration: '1000ms',
                                    transitionTimingFunction: 'ease',
                                    transitionDelay: '0ms',
                                }}
                                data-anima
                                data-time={1000}
                                aid="0.5738936811843882"
                            >
                                <hr
                                    id="DPLpC"
                                    className="hc-cmp-space space-lg  hidden-md   "
                                />
                                <h1 id="BdEnF" className="hc-cmp-title-tag    " style={{}}>
                                    The funny app, to share and listen your music
                                    <span className="dot">.</span>
                                </h1>
                                <p id="9EIqX" className="hc-cmp-text-block    " style={{}}>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
                                    do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                                    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                                    laboriso.
                                </p>
                                <hr id="RFBds" className="hc-cmp-space space-sm    " />
                                <div id="57Igh" className="hc-cmp-code-block    ">
                                    <a
                                        href="#"
                                        className="btn btn-sm text-bold btn-circle shadow-1 full-width-sm"
                                    >
                                        Download now
                                    </a>
                                    <span className="space-sm" />
                                    <a href="#" className="btn-text active hidden-sm">
                                        Discover the music
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <hr id="pWrRN" className="hc-cmp-space space-xs    " />
                            </div>
                            <div
                                id="column_I8mak"
                                className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-6   fade-bottom"
                                style={{
                                    position: 'relative',
                                    animationDuration: '1000ms',
                                    transitionTimingFunction: 'ease',
                                    transitionDelay: '0ms',
                                }}
                                data-anima
                                data-time={1000}
                                aid="0.8009226736862343"
                            >
                                <hr id="Q0JeD" className="hc-cmp-space space  visible-md   " />
                                <div id="cparo" className="hc-cmp-code-block    ">
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section
                    id="overview"
                    className="section-base hc-cmp-section  section-color  section-top-overflow "
                >
                    <div className="container ">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div
                                id="column_7sXOv"
                                className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-12  "
                                style={{}}
                            >
                                <div
                                    id="LbzXL"
                                    className="hc-component hc-cmp-grid-list grid-list   "
                                    data-columns={4}
                                    data-columns-lg={4}
                                    data-columns-md={2}
                                    data-columns-sm={2}
                                    data-columns-xs={1}
                                >
                                    <div className="grid-box">
                                        <div className="grid-item">
                                            <div
                                                id="gzuB5"
                                                className="cnt-box-top-icon    cnt-box hc-cmp-content-box  boxed scroll-to "
                                                data-href="#"
                                            >
                                                <i className=" im-bar-chart5 " />{' '}
                                                <div className="caption">
                                                    <h2>Real time chars</h2>
                                                    <p className>
                                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet consect sed do eiusmod
                                                        tempore.
                                                    </p>{' '}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="grid-item">
                                            <div
                                                id="ojQYr"
                                                className="cnt-box-top-icon    cnt-box hc-cmp-content-box  boxed scroll-to "
                                                data-href="#"
                                            >
                                                <i className=" im-cool-guy " />{' '}
                                                <div className="caption">
                                                    <h2>Premium support</h2>
                                                    <p className>
                                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet consect sed do eiusmod
                                                        tempore.
                                                    </p>{' '}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="grid-item">
                                            <div
                                                id="LrssQ"
                                                className="cnt-box-top-icon    cnt-box hc-cmp-content-box  boxed scroll-to "
                                                data-href="#"
                                            >
                                                <i className=" im-laptop-3 " />{' '}
                                                <div className="caption">
                                                    <h2>Cross platform</h2>
                                                    <p className>
                                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet consect sed do eiusmod
                                                        tempore.
                                                    </p>{' '}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="grid-item">
                                            <div
                                                id="D1I6L"
                                                className="cnt-box-top-icon    cnt-box hc-cmp-content-box  boxed scroll-to "
                                                data-href="#"
                                            >
                                                <i className=" im-security-settings " />{' '}
                                                <div className="caption">
                                                    <h2>Security features</h2>
                                                    <p className>
                                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet consect sed do eiusmod
                                                        tempore.
                                                    </p>{' '}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr
                                    id="8VOJz"
                                    className="hc-cmp-space space-lg  hidden-md   "
                                />
                                <hr id="YF7SG" className="hc-cmp-space space  visible-md   " />
                            </div>
                            <div
                                id="column_Z7CiC"
                                className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-12 align-items-center  "
                                style={{}}
                            >
                                <div
                                    id="column_NpKFs"
                                    className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-6 col-md-6   fade-left"
                                    style={{
                                        position: 'relative',
                                        animationDuration: '1000ms',
                                        transitionTimingFunction: 'ease',
                                        transitionDelay: '0ms',
                                    }}
                                    data-anima
                                    data-time={1000}
                                    aid="0.9379847219203462"
                                >
                                    <h2 id="mzEAU" className="hc-cmp-title-tag    " style={{}}>
                                        Social features to share <br />
                                        your favorite songs and playlists
                                        <span className="dot">.</span>
                                    </h2>
                                    <p id="sleBF" className="hc-cmp-text-block    " style={{}}>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametno sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
                                        ipsum dolor sit amete. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                                        exercitation ullamco sea takimata sanctus eslaboriso. Aipsum
                                        dolor sit amete sanctus artequis nostrud exercitation
                                        ullamco sea tassa.
                                    </p>
                                    <a
                                        id="XpodR"
                                        className="hc-cmp-button     btn-text scroll-to "
                                        href="#"
                                    >
                                        Explore services
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div
                                    id="column_chXnp"
                                    className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-6 col-md-6   fade-right"
                                    style={{
                                        position: 'relative',
                                        animationDuration: '1000ms',
                                        transitionTimingFunction: 'ease',
                                        transitionDelay: '0ms',
                                    }}
                                    data-anima
                                    data-time={1000}
                                    aid="0.17285515585305034"
                                >
                                    <div
                                        id="QWFUs"
                                        className="hc-component hc-cmp-image-grid-list grid-list  grid-wall-1  list-gallery"
                                        data-columns={2}
                                        data-columns-lg={2}
                                        data-columns-md={2}
                                        data-columns-sm={2}
                                        data-columns-xs={2}
                                        data-lightbox-anima="fade-top"
                                    >
                                        <div className="grid-box">
                                            <div className="grid-item">
                                                <a
                                                    className="img-box  img-scale"
                                                    href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/image-15.jpg"
                                                >
                                                    <img
                                                        alt=""
                                                        src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/image-15.jpg"
                                                        style={{}}
                                                    />
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="grid-item">
                                                <a
                                                    className="img-box  img-scale"
                                                    href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/image-11.jpg"
                                                >
                                                    <img
                                                        alt=""
                                                        src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/image-11.jpg"
                                                        style={{}}
                                                    />
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="grid-item">
                                                <a
                                                    className="img-box  img-scale"
                                                    href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/image-7.jpg"
                                                >
                                                    <img
                                                        alt=""
                                                        src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/image-7.jpg"
                                                        style={{}}
                                                    />
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="grid-item">
                                                <a
                                                    className="img-box  img-scale"
                                                    href="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/image-5.jpg"
                                                >
                                                    <img
                                                        alt=""
                                                        src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/music/wp-content/uploads/sites/7/2019/09/image-5.jpg"
                                                        style={{}}
                                                    />
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div
                                id="column_IoIkW"
                                className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-12  "
                                style={{}}
                            >
                                <hr
                                    id="SbfM5"
                                    className="hc-cmp-space space-lg  hidden-md   "
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div
                                id="column_GVc3l"
                                className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-12 align-items-center  "
                                style={{}}
                            >
                                <div
                                    id="column_BRP18"
                                    className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-6 col-md-6  "
                                    style={{ opacity: 0 }}
                                    data-anima="fade-left"
                                    data-time={1000}
                                >
                                    <div id="DF3xr" className="hc-cmp-code-block    ">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div
                                    id="column_ic4cg"
                                    className="hc-cmp-column hc-column col-lg-6 col-md-6  "
                                    style={{ opacity: 0 }}
                                    data-anima="fade-right"
                                    data-time={1000}
                                >
                                    <h2 id="dZZau" className="hc-cmp-title-tag    " style={{}}>
                                        Trusted by international <br />
                                        artists from all over the world
                                        <span className="dot">.</span>
                                    </h2>
                                    <p id="hTtlb" className="hc-cmp-text-block    " style={{}}>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametno sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
                                        ipsum dolor sit amete. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
                                        exercitation ullamco sea takimata sanctus eslaboriso. Aipsum
                                        dolor sit amete sanctus artequis nostrud exercitation
                                        ullamco sea tassa.
                                    </p>
                                    <a
                                        id="yA7P2"
                                        className="hc-cmp-button     btn-text scroll-to "
                                        href="#"
                                    >
                                        Explore services
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </main>
            <i className="scroll-top-btn scroll-top show" />
            <footer id="footer" className="align-left light footer-parallax">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-lg-3">
                            <h4>Company and team</h4>
                            <div className="menu-inner menu-inner-vertical">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Company details and team</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">News and blog</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Press area</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Affiliates and marketing</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-3">
                            <h4>Help and support</h4>
                            <div className="menu-inner menu-inner-vertical">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Help centre</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Feedbacks</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Request new features</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Contact us</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-3">
                            <h4>Learn more</h4>
                            <div className="menu-inner menu-inner-vertical">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Apps stores</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Partners</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Privacy and terms</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-3">
                            <h4>Follow us</h4>
                            <div className="icon-links icon-social icon-links-grid social-colors">
                                <a className="facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="#">
                                    <i className="icon-facebook" />
                                </a>
                                <a className="twitter" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="#">
                                    <i className="icon-twitter" />
                                </a>
                                <a
                                    className="instagram"
                                    target="_blank"
                                    rel="nofollow"
                                    href="#"
                                >
                                    <i className="icon-instagram" />
                                </a>
                                <a className="youtube" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="#">
                                    <i className="icon-youtube" />
                                </a>
                                <a className="linkedin" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="#">
                                    <i className="icon-linkedin" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="footer-bar">
                    <div className="container">
                        <span>
                            © Codrop LTD 2019. Codrop is a powerful Landing Page App Template
                            built with
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://themekit.dev/code/">
                                Themekit
                            </a>
                            by the
                            <a target="_blank" href="https://schiocco.com/">
                                Schiocco
                            </a>
                            Team.
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <img
                                src="http://themes.framework-y.com/codrop/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2019/08/logo-light.svg"
                                alt=""
                            />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

Comment: Which element has to have the zoom out effect?

Comment: The first section

Comment: I think somewhere there is a `tranform: scale(1.2)` animation in Codrop, which is not triggered in my implmenetation. I just do not see it what should trigger it. Maybe a JavaScript code.

Comment: @user19473296 CSS animation runs as soon as the match is found here, it says `.ken-burn-center > img` is found, run animation `ken-burn-in` for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He has an initial zoom value of 1.2, then zooms out to 1 in his ken-burn-in animation that spans 10 seconds.  Extracted to show below:

```
.ken-burn-center > img {
    animation: ken-burn-in 10s;
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

@keyframes ken-burn-in {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8hjxzkuq/

Comment: I see. ken-burn-center. But why that `Affiliates and marketing` text become visible?

Comment: @user19473296 See https://css-tricks.com/the-slideout-footer/ or Google "parallax footer" to see how to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

There is mainly 2 different ways, using either animation or transition.

animation is normally better when one want something running all the time, and transition is more efficient for e.g. hover effects.

Here is a start using animation.

Stack snippet

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

@keyframes breath {
  0%   { background-size: 100% auto; }
  50% { background-size: 140% auto; }
  100% { background-size: 100% auto; }
}

#bkg{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: breath 4s linear infinite;
  background: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/LXR5gFx.png") center center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="bkg"></div>
```